# .htaccess: rewrite to new URL structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to have the following URL redirect to a new structure:

- **Before**: `http://example.com/profile/?name=some-one`
- **After**: `http://example.com/profile/some-one/`

The `some-name` will change depending on the user's account, so I want that part to be dynamic. This is what I have for my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)name=(.*)
RewriteRule ^profile/$ /profile/$1/? [L,R=301]
```

According to this [online htaccess tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/), this would be the result:

```
http://example.com/profile//
```

Any help on clarifying why it's not carrying over the dynamic `some-name`? If it matters, this is for a WordPress site which already has the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)name=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile/%2/? [R=301,L]
```

Use % for vars captured in `RewriteCond`'s

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Is the first `RewriteCond` necessary? I tested it on [`.htaccess` tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) and I still get the expected result. Do I need the first line?

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan Only if you have multiple hosts that you need different rules for, otherwise no. Just added for completeness.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, appreciate it